# Load scripts in another folder

Tags: configuration, mpv

I want to change the `mpv.conf` mpv configuration file so that the scripts in the folder `/usr/share/mpv/scripts/` get loaded. For example the script `/usr/share/mpv/scripts/autosubsync/`.

I also need it to load the configuration in `/usr/share/doc/mpv/script-opts/autosubsync.conf`.

How can I do that?

I still want the scripts and options in the usual folder to get loaded. So this is to add another folder not to replace the usual user folders `~/.config/mpv/script-opts/` and `~/.config/mpv/scripts/`.

Comment: /usr/share/mpv/scripts/autosubsync/ can't be a script, since the trailing slash indicates, it is a directory. Or is the trailing slash wrong? Maybe you can load the /usr/share scripts from your personal conf file, maybe you just need to copy the files to the appropriate folder in ~/.config/mpv?

Comment: That's what I've done, but I still want to use the scripts at `/usr/share/mpv/scripts` by default. It would be simpler since it's installed there by `yay -S mpv-autosubsync-git` and it wouldn't require me to move the script to `~/.config/mpv/scripts` or call `mpv --scripts=/usr/share/mpv/scripts/ 'filepath'` every time.

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't no mpv at all. Nonetheless, you should correct your first paragraph and either remove the trailing slash, if it is indeed a script, or replace the word script with directory, if it isn't. To simplyfy the invocation of the program, you might define an alias (in your ~/.bashrc for persistence) `alias mpv="mpv --scripts=/usr/share/mpv/scripts/`". It needs a reopening of the terminal, if done via .bashrc.

Comment: starting from [here in the manual](https://mpv.io/manual/stable/#options-include), your question should be answered.